# It is possible to read csv file from the middle?

Tags: java, csv

Can read file from start index to end index.

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("file.csv")).skip(1000000).limit(1000).forEach(s-> {});
```

But it isn't performance. It is possible to read csv file performance from middle of file?

Comment: What does "it isn't performance" mean? This does everything that needs to be done and I doubt the implementation of each method is slow.

Comment: I know in which lines some lines are located. file size 15GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would java [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class methods help? Something like `seek`, `skipBytes`, etc. You can find tutorials.

Comment: It is possible if file have size 15GB?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how predictable it is, and on what exactly you mean by "middle", and what you consider to be "read from middle".

If the "middle" has to be an exact line, then you will have to read all the bytes before that middle, because otherwise you can miss on bytes that end lines (and the only way, with a CSV file, of knowing where line `N` is, is to have read exactly `N-1` end-of-line characters until arriving at that position). Having to read all bytes up to a point is linear in time, and is certainly not as fast as actually jumping there in 1 go - but it may count as "reading from middle" for you.

If the file is highly predictable (all lines have approximately the same length), and you do not care much about getting exactly at the middle, then you can always take the length of the file, `L`, and jump to the last position before position `L/2` which contains a newline character. The next position is, with high probability (since your file is predictable), the "middle line".